# Lumen framework routing error

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

i'm beginner Lumen framework. I have some problems.
Lumen routing not working or my mistakes.

```
$app->get('/front', function(){
    return 'Front';
});
```

Error is

```
NotFoundHttpException in Application.php line 1256:
in Application.php line 1256
at Application->handleDispatcherResponse(array('0')) in Application.php line 1212
at Application->Laravel\Lumen\{closure}() in Application.php line 1442
at Application->sendThroughPipeline(array(), object(Closure)) in Application.php line 1213
at Application->dispatch(object(Request)) in Application.php line 1153
at Application->run(object(Request)) in index.php line 29
```

And I already edited app.php Dotenv, `withFacades()`, `withEloquent()` uncommented. 
And public/index.php edited

```
$request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture();
$app->run($request);
```

Sorry for my english. Please help me.

Comment: What is the url you trying.. `yourproject.com/front` like this ?

Comment: That's the exception Lumen throws when a route is not matched, thus a 404 Not Found error. How are you accessing that route: `domanin.com/front`?

Comment: sorry url http://localhost/lumen/public/front

Comment: You should configure your HTTP server to point the document root at the `public` directory. What HTTP server are you using?

Comment: Try like this `localhost/lumen/front` (If you configured your .htaccess to do so )

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen how?

Comment: To configure  `.htaccess` If you have `server.php` in your root document rename it to `index.php` then, move your `.htaccess` file from `public` to `root`

Comment: you can access your lumen routes on `localhost:8000/front`. If your lumen serving on 8000 port

Comment: @BatnyamBaasanjav How are you doing other calls ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should replace the code in `index.php` from:

```
$app->run();
```

with:

```
$app->run($app['request']);
```

Hope it will help you to run your application. You can also check it here as well [Install & fix Lumen Errors](http://www.tradetu.com/blog/install-lumen-by-laravel-on-windows-with-apache/).